# Allow access to file ONLY FROM specific PHP file/ dir on same server

Tags: php, ajax, apache, .htaccess

I've been pulling my hair off trying to find a solution for **denying access to a file for all AJAX/ PHP/ in-browser requests EXCEPT when they come from one (other) directory/ file on the same server.** 
I have a .htaccess in the directory of the JSON file. The file is fetched by a CMS plugin as follows (pretty standard):

1. Javascript makes an AJAX call to a PHP file on the server, called `handler.php`.
2. `handler.php` then retrieves the contents of the file and returns it to JS.

I can't use rewrite rules, as it is not a prereq. for the CMS. I also can't set a known domain name, as it is dynamic. Ideally I would do `Allow from SELF`.
I have tried the following .htaccess configs without luck:

```
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from all
Allow From <ownDomainName/subpath>
```

Or:

```
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from all
Allow From <ownDomainName/subpath/fileName.ext>
```

I tried with `setEnv` directive too, and a mixture of others involving using `<Files>`, `<Directory>` and `<Location>`. If I just `Deny from All` the PHP cannot access it. Is there any solution for restricting access to a JSON file?
Also, does it have anything to do with the fact that I am testing on `localhost`?

Comment: Your question states 'i cannot set a known domain name' but then in your two examples, you reference a domain name?

Comment: @greg_diesel Your question is pertinent, but I tried with possible solutions I found, and none of these allowed a 'wildcard', eg someth. like `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` for PHP...

Comment: If header.php is opening yourfile.json and outputting the results to an ajax client...     The user can read the result of header.php (which is your secret json) in their browser with just a little investigating.

Comment: <File> directive could be the easiest solution

Comment: Looks like first of all you need to learn the difference between an HTTP request vs access to a file via the file system.

Comment: And that's what I just did! I was sending the data via a URL instead of an FS relative path, which happened to work before because I set the `.htaccess` to `Allow from all` *shame*. It's all good now

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 types of access to the file.

1. From web, where .htaccess rules or server (apache) config is applied.
2. By app or script running on the server machine, where filesystem permissions are applied.

So you can deny all requests in .htaccess file, but PHP script still can access the file via FS (dependent on FS permissions).

Comment: He said: "I can't use rewrite rules"